# unable to install Nodejs on centos-fatal error: headers: No such file or directory

Tags: node.js, centos7

I am trying to install nodejs from source. When I run 'make install' I am getting:

```
     node-v6.3.1]# make install
make -C out BUILDTYPE=Release V=1
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/centos/node-v6.3.1/out'
  g++  -I../deps/gtest -I../deps/gtest/include  -pthread -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -m64 -Wno-missing-field-initializers -O3 -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions -std=gnu++0x -MMD -MF /home/centos/node-v6.3.1/out/Release/.deps//home/centos/node-v6.3.1/out/Release/obj.target/gtest/deps/gtest/src/gtest-death-test.o.d.raw   -c -o /home/centos/node-v6.3.1/out/Release/obj.target/gtest/deps/gtest/src/gtest-death-test.o ../deps/gtest/src/gtest-death-test.cc
In file included from ../deps/gtest/include/gtest/internal/gtest-internal.h:40:0,
                 from ../deps/gtest/include/gtest/internal/gtest-death-test-internal.h:40,
                 from ../deps/gtest/include/gtest/gtest-death-test.h:41,
                 from ../deps/gtest/src/gtest-death-test.cc:34:
../deps/gtest/include/gtest/internal/gtest-port.h:259:41: fatal error: ctype.h: No such file or directory
 #include <ctype.h>   // for isspace, etc
```

I installed c and c++ libraries as  well using: `yum -y install gcc gcc-c++ make`.

I also tried to install via rpm:

```
    error: %pre(nodejs-1:6.3.1-1nodesource.el7.centos.x86_64) scriptlet failed, exit                                                                                         status 127
Error in PREIN scriptlet in rpm package 1:nodejs-6.3.1-1nodesource.el7.centos.x8                                                                                        6_64
  Verifying  : 1:nodejs-6.3.1-1nodesource.el7.centos.x86_64                 1/1

Failed:
  nodejs.x86_64 1:6.3.1-1nodesource.el7.centos
```

Could you please anyone help what might be the issue. Thanks

Comment: Have you tried from this link https://nodejs.org/en/download/package-manager/#enterprise-linux-and-fedora ?

Comment: Tried but got similar issue `error: %pre(nodejs-1:6.3.1-1nodesource.el7.centos.x86_64) scriptlet failed, exit status 127
Error in PREIN scriptlet in rpm package 1:nodejs-6.3.1-1nodesource.el7.centos.x86_64
  Verifying  : 1:nodejs-6.3.1-1nodesource.el7.centos.x86_64 `

Comment: Have you already installed another nodejs version? You may need to remove current nodejs

Comment: I removed installed nodejs and tried but the same issue. Even I tried by launching new EC2 centos7, issue till persists. Is this the issue with centos7?

Comment: You may like to install using [NVM](https://github.com/creationix/nvm)

Comment: Today I tried from the first link you referred and its worked. I cleaned repo with  `yum clean all` and reinstalled nodejs with `curl --silent --location https://rpm.nodesource.com/setup_6.x | bash -`. Thanks much